# Is it possible to iterate over a list of numbers in tsql?

Tags: sql-server, list, t-sql, iteration

I have a comma separated list of personIDs: `1265, 8632`.
What I want to do is something I'd like to indicate by a chunk of pseudo-code, which does not work, of course.

```
declare @max int = (select count(*) from dbo.tablePersons)-1
declare @cnt = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT personID FROM dbo.tablePersons 
        WHERE (1265, 8632)[@cnt] 
        IS NOT IN SELECT personID FROM  dbo.tablePersons
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
    END
```

I want to iterate over the list `1265, 8632` and check whether the IDs in the list are NOT there in `SELECT personID FROM dbo.tablePersons`. The goal is to find all those IDs in my list that are there in `SELECT personID FROM  dbo.tablePersons`.

Given the fact that this pseudo-code is not viable -is there a kind of a workaround?

Comment: Avoid looping or cursor whenever possible. SQL Server is optimized to do operations in a set basis, not 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```sql
DECLARE @mockperson TABLE(ID INT, PersName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockperson VALUES
 (1,'pers 1')
,(2,'pers 2');

DECLARE @yourlist VARCHAR(100)='1,999,2';
```

--The query splits the given list and checks for numbers `NOT IN` the person table

```sql
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@yourlist,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS TheListAsXml
)
SELECT x.value('text()[1]','int')
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY TheListAsXml.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
WHERE x.value('text()[1]','int') NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM @mockperson);
```

### Starting with v2016

With [`STRING_SPLIT()` (v2016+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) this would be the same approach, just easier

```sql
SELECT *
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@yourlist,',') AS A
WHERE A.value NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM @mockperson);
```